# Is it ok that my deep learning model shows nearly 100% accuracy and validation accuracy after one epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make a model for the signature verification problem, so the dataset contains nearly 800 (already augmented) samples. I am assuming that this is the core of the problem I am getting.

Just to clarify the weird choice of hyperparameters, I am writing a school report on the effect of CNN configurations on models performance (this is the first model I did).

pls correct me if you notice any misconception in my explanation/code

```
model =  Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1,1), input_shape = X.shape[1:] ))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1,1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

here are the results

1st model: 1x1 kernel size and global pooling
2nd: 3x3 and average pooling
3rd: 5x5 and max-pooling

[image]

Comment: Note since you have a global max pooling layer you don't need a flatten layer

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you're dataset are not properly randomized and heterogeneous, maybe have a look there.

Comment: I shuffled it before training, if I will add Chinese signatures too, would the increase of dataset improve this situation>? I am hesitating, as I think it has different patterns(?), features to extract, so it needs a separate model.

Comment: Maybe test it on new data to see if it is really a good model or an overfitting?